# Change the color of a bullet in a html list?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

All I want is to be able to change the color of a bullet in a list to a light gray. It defaults to black, and I can't figure out how to change it.

I know I could just use an image; I'd rather not do that if I can help it.

Comment: I would just go with an image myself and avoid the extra markup. It's probably the more efficient solution

Comment: Who cares about "extra" markup like this... seriously, you lose nothing by doing it.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

The bullet gets its color from the text.  So if you want to have a different color bullet than text in your list you'll have to add some markup.

Wrap the list text in a span:

```
<ul>
  <li><span>item #1</span></li>
  <li><span>item #2</span></li>
  <li><span>item #3</span></li>
</ul>
```

Then modify your style rules slightly:

```
li {
  color: red; /* bullet color */
}
li span {
  color: black; /* text color */
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! I have a list of links and the links already have a different color style applied to them anyway.

Comment: This is not the nicest way to do this. For instance, this will not work when you have a cms around with a WYSIWYG editor. The <span> elements will not get rendered. What you may want is to work with :before and :after and leave out the bullits itself. This is actually a very bad practice.

Comment: @KoenHoutman, at the time this was written (2008) it was the only technique with reasonable support. Even today it is not a bad practice and still is the technique with the broadest browser support, although I agree that today (in most cases) I would opt for using `:before` as in Marc's answer below.

Comment: Since you're only changing the presentation of the text, a `b` tag would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 45):

I managed this without adding markup, but instead using li:before. This obviously has all the limitations of `:before` (no old IE support), but it seems to work with IE8, Firefox and Chrome after some very limited testing. It's working in our controller environment, wondering if anyone could check this. The bullet style is also limited by what's in unicode.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    li {
      list-style: none;
    }

    li:before {
      /* For a round bullet */
      content:'\2022';
      /* For a square bullet */
      /*content:'\25A0';*/
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      max-width: 0px;
      max-height: 0px;
      left: -10px;
      top: -0px;
      color: green;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the more moern way with CSS3, compared to the accepted answer

Answer (score 18):

This was impossible in 2008, but it's becoming possible soon (hopefully)!

According to [The W3C CSS3 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-lists-3/#marker-pseudo-element), you can have full control over any number, glyph, or other symbol generated before a list item with the `::marker` pseudo-element.
To apply this to the most voted answer's solution:

```
<ul>
  <li>item #1</li>
  <li>item #2</li>
  <li>item #3</li>
</ul>

li::marker {
  color: red; /* bullet color */
}
li {
  color: black /* text color */
}
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/9Srpq/)

Note, though, that **as of July 2016**, this solution is only a part of the W3C Working Draft and does not work in any major browsers, yet.

If you want this feature, do these:

- [**Blink** (Chrome, Opera, Vivaldi, Yandex, etc.): star Chromium's issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=457718&thanks=457718&ts=1423675756)
- [**Gecko** (Firefox, Iceweasel, etc.): Click "(vote)" on this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=205202)
- <s>[**Trident** (IE, Windows web views): Click "I can too" under "X User(s) can reproduce this bug"](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedbackdetail/view/1125247/support-marker-pseudo-element#tabs)</s>
  <sup>Trident development has ceased</sup>
- [**EdgeHTML** (MS Edge, Windows web views, Windows Modern apps): Click "Vote" on this prpopsal](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/257854-internet-explorer-platform/suggestions/7084750-css-3-marker-pseudo-element)
- [**Webkit** (Safari, Steam, WebOS, etc.): CC yourself to this bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=141477)

Comment: Pretty full support since 2020. Definitely the way to go these days.

Answer (score 6):

```
<ul>
  <li style="color: #888;"><span style="color: #000">test</span></li>
</ul>
```

the big problem with this method is the extra markup. (the span tag)

Comment: Since you're only changing the presentation of the text, a `b` tag would be more appropriate.

Comment: When this was written, the b tag was in the middle of being deprecated in favour of strong tag.    But yes, you're correct, now a b tag would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Hello maybe this answer is late but is the correct one to achieve this.

Ok the fact is that you must specify an internal tag to make the LIst text be on the usual black (or what ever you want to get it). But is also true that you can REDEFINE any TAGS and internal tags with CSS. So the best way to do this use a SHORTER tag for the redefinition

Usign this CSS definition:

```
li { color: red; }
li b { color: black; font_weight: normal; }
.c1 { color: red; }
.c2 { color: blue; }
.c3 { color: green; }
```

And this html code:

```
<ul>
<li><b>Text 1</b></li>
<li><b>Text 2</b></li>
<li><b>Text 3</b></li>
</ul>
```

You get required result. Also you can make each disc diferent color:

```
<ul>
    <li class="c1"><b>Text 1</b></li>
    <li class="c2"><b>Text 2</b></li>
    <li class="c3"><b>Text 3</b></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: you should use <span>. also, <b> is deprecated.

Comment: Counter point to @the_drow, <b> is not deprecated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348683/will-the-b-and-i-tags-ever-become-deprecated

Comment: Setting a default color that's applied to a specific selector fixed my issue. Thank you for this tip.

Answer (score 2):

Just do a bullet in a graphics program and use `list-style-image`:

```
ul {
  list-style-image:url('gray-bullet.gif');
}
```

Comment: The OP explicitly didn't want to use a picture, but I came across this looking for a general way to replace the bullet. So I think this answer is nice for completeness.

Comment: Here is one with SVG circle, which one can colorize easily: `list-style-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 512 512'%3E%3Ccircle cx='256' cy='256' r='256' fill='#ff0000' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the text within the list item with a span (or some other element) and apply the bullet color to the list item and the text color to the span.

Answer (score 0):

As per [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#lists),

> The list properties ... do not allow authors to specify distinct style (colors, fonts, alignment, etc.) for the list marker ...

But the idea with a span inside the list above should work fine!

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
<li style="color:#ddd;"><span style="color:#000;">List Item</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery if you have lots of pages and don't need to go and edit the markup your self.

here is a simple example:

```
$("li").each(function(){
var content = $(this).html();
var myDiv = $("<div />")
myDiv.css("color", "red"); //color of text.
myDiv.html(content);
$(this).html(myDiv).css("color", "yellow"); //color of bullet
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For a 2008 question, I thought I might add a more recent and up-to-date answer on how you could go about changing the colour of bullets in a list.

If you are willing to use external libraries, [Font Awesome gives you scalable vector icons](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/#list), and when combined with [Bootstrap's helper classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes) (eg. `text-success`), you can make some pretty cool and customisable lists.

I have expanded on the extract from [the Font Awesome list examples page](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/#list) below:

> Use `fa-ul` and `fa-li` to easily replace default bullets in unordered lists.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul class="fa-ul">
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-circle"></i>List icons</li>
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-check-square text-success"></i>can be used</li>
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-spinner fa-spin text-primary"></i>as bullets</li>
  <li><i class="fa-li fa fa-square text-danger"></i>in lists</li>
</ul>
```

Font Awesome [(mostly) supports IE8](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie8-font-face), and only supports IE7 if you use the [older version 3.2.1](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/3.2.1/get-started/#need-ie7).

Answer (score 0):

It works as well if we set color for each elements for example:
I added some Margin to left now.

```
<article class="event-item">
    <p>Black text here</p>
</article>

.event-item{
    list-style-type: disc;
    display: list-item;
    color: #ff6f9a;
     margin-left: 25px;
}
.event-item p {
    margin: 0;
    color: initial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple and fast option:

```
.ul li::marker {
    color: #229fff;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<ul style="color: red;">
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

One

Two

Three

Answer (score -1):

You could use CSS to attain this.  By specifying the list in the color and style of your choice, you can then also specify the text as a different color.

Follow the example at http://www.echoecho.com/csslists.htm.

Answer (score -2):

Just use CSS:

```
<li style='color:#e0e0e0'>something</li>
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought too... but styling li color changes the color of the text as well as the bullet.

Answer (score -5):

You'll want to set a "list-style" via CSS, and give it a color: value.  Example:

```
ul.colored {list-style: color: green;}
```