# color the ordered list in html

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an easy way to change the color of a bullet in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76564/is-there-an-easy-way-to-change-the-color-of-a-bullet-in-a-list)

I have an ordered list as

```
 ul{
  list-style-type:circle;
 }    

<ul>
<li>one</li>
<li>two</li>
</ul>
```

How do I fill the circle with blue color and not the font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is unordered list, not ordered, ordered is OL and elements has particular explicit order.
Second, you can set color of li element what will trigger bullet to change color

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you would have to create an image to use as a bullet and then set that via `list-style-image`.

Comment: you don't need to do that, you just can change color of particular `li` element

Comment: Certainly, but that would change the color of the text as well, which the OP wants to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
<li><span>one</span></li>
<li><span>two</span></li>
</ul>
```

If you use html code as above you could set the color for the `ul` to be blue and the color for `li span` black. That should give the desired effect.

BTW: your list is an unordered list.

Comment: True, you could add redundant markup as well.

Comment: Using images could be a better solution since it does not require any markup changes, but if using images is out of the question then this would be the only alternative.