# How to change css of a li bullet?

Tags: html, css

```
<li class="bullet-style" type="square">This is a test</li>

.bullet-style {
   color:red;
}
```

But this doesnot reflect. So, How can I chnage the color of a li bullet

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76564/is-there-an-easy-way-to-change-the-color-of-a-bullet-in-a-list

Comment: `type` is not a valid attribute for the `li` element. Only for `input` (afaik).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you would need this, but to answer on your question: give the list-item itself a span and give the span a different color than the span.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/HrEwS/

Answer (score 0):

Use list-style-image and use a red square as your image.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-image.asp