# About <ol> and style

Tags: css, html-lists

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there an easy way to change the color of a bullet in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76564/is-there-an-easy-way-to-change-the-color-of-a-bullet-in-a-list)

Is it possible to apply a specific style to the numeral of a `<ol>` list?

Example:

1. foo
2. bar

I need "1." and "2." to be red, "foo" and "bar" to be blue.

Comment: @BoltClock, I don't see the reason for closing such a question/ due to the **answer**. Rather close the other one.

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan: I didn't close the question as a duplicate because the answers are the same. I closed it because the questions are the same. And I have no idea what you mean by "Rather close the other one."

Comment: @BoltClock That means that actually Calderan should search old / accepted questions to spread new technologies and knowledge? ... Without being rewarded... Just a tohught. Should be a *Meta*.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - no. It means that people with problems should search before posting.

Comment: @ChrisF . That's not the point if you compare the two answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using `before` pseudoelement and `counter` function you can achieve this: http://jsfiddle.net/QXe7K/

```
ul { counter-reset : item; }
li { color         : blue; }
li:before {
    counter-increment : item;
    content           : counter(item) ". ";
    color             : red;
}
```

no extra markup is required. it works also on IE8 (and on every other modern browser)

Comment: Is this a crossbrowser solution? (I think IE7 is also a browser...)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan see my update. IE7 has a worldwide market share < 2% (http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201205-201205-bar). So it's not something to worry about.

Comment: Your update still thinks IE7 is not a browser ;)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I think the key word is *modern*; but then again people still consider IE6 to be a browser.

Comment: `:before` is a pseudo-element.

Comment: I personally don't consider IE a browser at all (IE9-). But some older-aged visitors don't think like me. And we  - as a web developers should respect their choices (*eventually* suggesting a better solution).

Comment: right, just an inattention :) @BoltClock

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan if you are concerned in IE<8 users, just use conditional comments and serve a default `<ol>` styling with a single colour, or just use extra markup.

Comment: You got my attention. Let's forget those shitty browsers and +10000 from me :) Deleted my old-fashioned answer. Let's finally turn a new WEB 3.0 page ;) starting from SO