# How to style the number on a html list?

Tags: css, html-lists

Is it possible to style or increase the size of the numbers **only** on a ordered list?

I am planning on turning a ordered list `ol` into something like [wikihow](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-CSS) steps using CSS only.

Here is a example to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/ejRzy/1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to change the color of a bullet in a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76564/is-there-an-easy-way-to-change-the-color-of-a-bullet-in-a-list)

Comment: Not possible. You can add the the numbers yourself in HTML.

Comment: @iambriansreed it is possible; just not 100% cross-compatible.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It can be done using CSS3 but not 100% cross browser (namely IE7). using the pseudo :before element and counter-reset and counter-increment you can hide the list-style and create your own.

here is an article outlining how: [Styling ordered list numbers](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201105/styling_ordered_list_numbers/)

and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/YLw3k/) is a demo built from that article.

Also in case of the dreaded link rot - here is the main CSS code required (this can be applied to any ordered list)

```
ol {
    counter-reset:li; /* Initiate a counter */
    margin-left:0; /* Remove the default left margin */
    padding-left:0; /* Remove the default left padding */
}
ol > li {
    position:relative; /* Create a positioning context */
    margin:0 0 6px 2em; /* Give each list item a left margin to make room for the numbers */
    padding:4px 8px; /* Add some spacing around the content */
    list-style:none; /* Disable the normal item numbering */
    border-top:2px solid #666;
    background:#f6f6f6;
}
ol > li:before {
    content:counter(li); /* Use the counter as content */
    counter-increment:li; /* Increment the counter by 1 */
    /* Position and style the number */
    position:absolute;
    top:-2px;
    left:-2em;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:2em;
    /* Some space between the number and the content in browsers that support
       generated content but not positioning it (Camino 2 is one example) */
    margin-right:8px;
    padding:4px;
    border-top:2px solid #666;
    color:#fff;
    background:#666;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
}
li ol,
li ul {margin-top:6px;}
ol ol li:last-child {margin-bottom:0;}​
```

This code will produce a custom ordered list; albeit not the style you asked for. I will leave the customization work upto you :) cheers

Answer (score 13):

kind of.... style your ordered list with the font size you want for the numbers,  then wrap all your list items in spans, and give them a different style.

http://jsfiddle.net/keith_nicholas/MEHXj/

Comment: That's a good alternative, the correct answer is that it is not possible though

Comment: sure,  but in the spirit of stackoverflow, we don't stop at it not being possible, we start looking for the ways we can get around things to achieve what we want :)

Comment: While @rlemon's answer is the best, IMO, this answer is probably the most cross-browser compliant, even though it uses more markup. Why the downvotes on it?