# Numbering whole items inside different parents (with jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to numbering of DL like this,

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <dl>
            <dt>**1**</dt>
            <dd>...</dd>
        </dl>
        <dl>
            <dt>**2**</dt>
            <dd>...</dd>
        </dl>
    </li>
</ul>

<hr>

<ul>
    <li>
        <dl>
            <dt>**3**</dt>
            <dd>...</dd>
        </dl>
        <dl>
            <dt>**4**</dt>
            <dd>...</dd>
        </dl>
        <dl>
            <dt>**5**</dt>
            <dd>...</dd>
        </dl>
    </li>
</ul>
```

so i trired this,

```
    $('dl dt').each(function() {
        var mydl = $(this).parents('dl').index;
        $(this).text(mydl);
    })
```

but doesn't work... 
so, how can I just count and numbering of whole DL, regardless of differents parents?
please help me. thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Since you want sequential number across all `dt`s

```
 $('dl dt').text(function (i) {
     return i + 1;
 })
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3r33pmk9/)

Since you want to set its text you can use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) which will receive the current element's index with respect to the used element set as its first param(0 based index)

Answer (score 0):

Try using **CSS** as following:

```
<dl class="faq">

<dt>How much wood would a wood chuck chuck if a wood chuck could chuck wood?</dt>
<dd>1,000,000</dd>

<dt>What is the air-speed velocity of an unladen swallow?</dt>
<dd>What do you mean? An African or European swallow?</dd>

<dt>Why did the chicken cross the road?</dt>
<dd>To get to the other side</dd>
```

```
.faq {
    counter-reset: my-badass-counter;
}
.faq dt:before {
    content: counter(my-badass-counter);
    counter-increment: my-badass-counter;
}
```

**Reference:**

[Numbering In Style](http://css-tricks.com/numbering-in-style/)

[How to style the number on a html list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182775/how-to-style-the-number-on-a-html-list)

Answer (score 0):

The script must run when the element loaded, or place most bottom of the body tag. 
and "index" is a function, you need "()".
Try it!

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('dl dt').each(function() {
            var mydl = $(this).parents('dl').index();
            $(this).text(mydl);
        })
    });

</script>
```

references : http://devdocs.io/jquery/index/index

Comment: I also tried this. but it counts only inside each LI. but thank you for your answer :)