# How strike through a bullet in list

Tags: css

We have eBook, in that one of the list has strike through the text as well as the bullet. i can able to strike the text using  (text-decoration: line-through;). But i can strike through the bullet in the list, please help me to get a solution?

Comment: Here is some reference, please also make your question clear http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182775/how-to-style-the-number-on-a-html-list   http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201105/styling_ordered_list_numbers/

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to implement
with Order list 
HTML :

```
<body>
    This fiddle is used to demonstrate the list styling with CSS
    <ol>
        <li> Item 1 </li>
        <li> Item 2 </li>
        <li> Item 3 </li>
        <li> Item 4 </li>    
    </ol>
</body>
```

and CSS :

```
ol li
{
 list-style-type: none;
 counter-increment: item;
 text-decoration:line-through;   
}
ol li::before
{
   content:counter(item) ".";
    text-decoration:line-through;
}
```

With unordered list, it is a little bit more complicated

HTML:

```
<body>
    This fiddle is used to demonstrate the unordered list styling with CSS
    <ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>

</ul>
</body>
```

and CSS:

```
ul{
   float:left;
}
li {
  list-style: circle;
  list-style-position: inside;
  margin-top:8px;

}
li:after{
    border-top:1px solid red;
    display:block;
    content:"";
    margin-top:-8px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, but still the bullet is not strike, the text alone got strike through.