# How can I color an OL's number separately from its content without using pseudo-elements?

Tags: html, css, html-lists, pseudo-element

**I've already looked at [Is there an easy way to change the color of a bullet in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76564/is-there-an-easy-way-to-change-the-color-of-a-bullet-in-a-list). This question's answers do not help me, as I have no control over the HTML structure. This is for a CSS library, not a particular webpage or site.**

Let's say I have the following code:

```
<style>
* {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}
#too {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
</style>
<ol>
    <li id="won">Item 1</li>
    <li id="too">Item 2</li>
    <li id="tre">Item 3</li>
</ol>
```

The second list element is supposed to be highlighted by inverting the background and foreground colors, but in doing this, the number for the item is also changed in this case.

**Is there any way I can do this while keeping the number for item 2 its initial color?** I've seen solutions with the `::before` pseudo-element and the `content` CSS attribute, but these do *not* work with the HTML5 `value` attribute for `li` elements.

Whatever answer you give, it should be semantic with current CSS3. This is because the final implementation will use `:target` to highlight the target element, and thus the HTML structure is not guaranteed.

Comment: If you can't use pseudo elements, you must use additional markup.  There isn't much choice in this case.  Could you clarify what this means:  "these do not work with the HTML5 value attribute for li elements"?

Comment: Though nominally about numbers and not bullets, this is effective a duplicate of question(s) about coloring list bullets. The problems and the techniques are basically the same.

Comment: The other answers don't help me. As I said,t he solution must be _only_ CSS3, as the HTML structure is not guaranteed. This is not for a webpage, but for a CSS library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the [accepted answer to the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76564/is-there-an-easy-way-to-change-the-color-of-a-bullet-in-a-list/76626#76626):

> The bullet gets its color from the text.

Technically speaking, this is because the list marker (the term given by [CSS2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#lists) to mean the bullet or number) generates its own anonymous box that's a child of the principal list item box. This marker box will always inherit styles from the principal box where applicable.

There is no way to target just the list marker box, or prevent it from inheriting styles from the principal box, using CSS2.1.

---

It's interesting to note, however, that it was intended in [CSS2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-CSS2-20080411/generate.html#q11) to allow the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements to `display: marker`, essentially allowing you to style them independently of the principal box of the element containing them (overriding `list-style` in the process). Unfortunately this feature was removed in CSS2.1, and I don't have any sources handy that explain why it was dropped.

Today, in CSS2.1, while you can still apply counter styles to `::before` and `::after`, you cannot make them act like real list markers. In both specifications, you weren't able to alter the values of the markers from within the markup either.

That said, while `display: marker` is no longer in CSS2.1, the concept of styling list markers is being revisited in the new [Lists and Counters module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-lists), with the introduction of a `::marker` pseudo-element designed specifically to target the list marker, allowing you to do something like this:

```css
*, ::marker {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}

#too {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

Of course, this doesn't work anywhere since it's just a proposal. Hopefully that will change someday, but it's always good to know that it's being considered.

Comment: Wow, this really adds something to SO... I'm gonna go to that other question and tell them this :3

Comment: @Supuhstar: You're right; what I just found and added is pretty applicable to that other question too. Doesn't mean your question is a duplicate though, since it's specific enough to stand on its own just fine - that's why I reopened and answered it here. I'm pretty hesitant on bumping another question with an answer that only works in theory though :)

Comment: I feel that this "theory" will become practice within the year, so I'm confident enough accepting this as an answer. After all, browsers (esp. Chrome) seem quick to adopt propositional standards, these days.

Comment: As of March 2014 no major browsers have as yet implemented this. (For anyone still trying to find it).

Answer (score -1):

Try like below, It will help you

**CSS:**

```
<style>
* {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}
#too span{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
</style>
```

**HTML:**

```
<ol>
    <li id="won"><span>Item 1</span></li>
    <li id="too"><span>Item 2</span></li>
    <li id="tre"><span>Item 3</span></li>
</ol>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: `**as I have no control over the HTML structure**` you missed this bit