# CSS says bulleted text is black; How do I use HTML to make it another color for certain web pages?

Tags: html, css

Our website's CSS says bulleted text should appear in black. How do I use HTML to make it another color for certain web pages? I tried coding the html but wasn't able to render a color other than black.

```
<ul>
<li><span style="line-height: 1.714285714;"><a href="URL" target="_blank">Log in to the                                     portal</a>.</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you want "Log in to the" to be in another color or the bullets?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to change the color of a bullet in a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76564/is-there-an-easy-way-to-change-the-color-of-a-bullet-in-a-list)

Comment: P.S. `line-height` has nothing to do with color.

Comment: @TylerH, What made you believe that he thought that `line-height` was for color..?

Comment: @Sifu because he is trying to change the color, but the only style here is `line-height`.

Comment: Do you want to change the color of the bullet or of the link? What is the current CSS? What did you *actually* try`? (The code included shows no effort of trying to change any color.)

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela I believe his question is pretty straight forward and precise : "How do I use HTML to make a bulleted **text** another color for certain web pages?". The answer is simple enough that or : He didn't search on google/internet,or he didn't find it. In which cases, we close for dupe or we answer the question.

Comment: @david you are using an a tag. It is more important than the span or the li itself. so you have to put the `style="color: (thecolor);"` on the a tag.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a style like this to change the color of the list items:

```css
ul.colorlist li a {

    color:red; 
}
```

This can be placed in external or embedded CSS and will specifically change the color of links within the list(s) that the class is applied to (a link is shown in your example code). If you only want to change text within the list:

```css
ul.colorlist li {

    color:red; 
}
```

Either way, you can then apply the class to the list(s) like this:

```html
<ul class="colorlist">
```

Answer (score 1):

## A quick and dirty way: Inline styles

CSS defined styles will be overridden by inline style attributes of HTML elements.

```
<li>
    <!-- Wrap the text in a span and add a style attribute (just like @Sifu's answer) -->
    <span style="color: red;">some text</span>
</li>
```

But it is more likely that the CSS coloring the text from your example comes from the `a` (link) tag. If you want to use inline styles, you can add the style attribute on the link itself.

```
<li>
    <!-- I've omitted the span's style attribute for these examples. -->
    <span><a style="color: red;">some text</a></span>
</li>
```

If you can edit the HTML but not the CSS then this may be the only option you have but unless you have no other choice, there is a better way...

## A better way

If you can edit/add to the website's CSS then it is much better practice to change the color of these HTML elements from the CSS.

There are a multitude of ways that CSS selectors can be written to target HTML elements depending on not only what is available but also what mood the designer was in when they wrote it.

### example

#### starting css

```
a { color: blue; }
li { color: black; }
```

#### starting html

```
<li><span><a href="#">text</a></span></li>
```

In this one you would decide if you want to change the style for just this link or all links in this list or all links in all lists or any other combination.

#### changing just this link

Add a class to that link to identify that it is a special kind of link:

```
<li><span><a href="#" class="myfancykindoflink">text</a></span></li>
```

Add a CSS selector for that class:

```
/* in CSS a class selector is more specific than a type selector
 * so this overrides the `a` style specified above.
 */
.myfancykindoflink { color: red; }
```

#### changing all links in this list

Add a class to that list to identify that it is a special kind of list:

```
<ul class="myfancykindoflist">
    <li><span><a href="#">text</a></span></li>
</ul>
```

Add a CSS selector for links in that class:

```
.myfancykindoflist a { color: red; }
```

Comment: I believe that the poster asked for a solution in HTML, not in CSS. Otherwise I would of answered with the proper CSS method. But eh, who am I to speak.

Comment: @Sifu good point, the poster did ask for an HTML solution

Answer (score -4):

What about this : (Inline style)

```
<li>
     <span style="line-height: 1.714285714; color: red;">
         <a href="URL" target="_blank">Log in to the portal</a>.
     </span>
</li>
```

Change the color to the one you want.

This will override any CSS color property.

Comment: Thanks I used the inline style with success. My CSS knowledge is limited so I'll stick with the inline for now. Thank you both.

Comment: Ugh, inline style r baaaaaad

Comment: Thanks for the further insight regarding ways to remedy this in the CSS. I'll ask a friend for some help with that so we do this the best way. What makes inline styles less ideal of a solution anyway?

Comment: @DavidK Because in the best world, you should be able to see any styling in the CSS page. Any overriding behind the scene is sub-optimal. Thing is, it is much simpler to do an inline-style for a lonely line, then making a CSS class for it. But then again, making a CSS class means that you could **reuse** that class later on if you need to. It's just better in many many ways.

Comment: +1 because while i agree that inline styles are bad, this answers the question that was asked.

Comment: There usually a dozen differant solutions to every HTML problem, and the best one is the important one. Inline styles is a last resort, not a 'good enough' solution.

Comment: @Michael, tell me an other pure HTML solution, go ahead. This is the only pure HTML solution. How is it not 'good enough'?

Comment: The answer is a 'pure html' solution doesn't exist!

Comment: @Michael Okay, you are going to throw the : *"You used inline CSS, This is not **pure** html bblrbrberlberl"*. This is not worth my time anymore. You clearly understood what I meant.